# Storing sessions in db

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Have just modified config.php like so:

```
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'cisession';  //[changed]
$config['sess_expiration']  = 7200;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = TRUE;  //[changed]
$config['sess_use_database']    = TRUE;  //[changed]
$config['sess_table_name']  = 'cisessions';  //[changed]
$config['sess_match_ip']    = TRUE;  //[changed]
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 300;
```

And everytime I refresh the page, I have a new session_id when I print the session with:

```
echo'<pre>SESSION:';
print_r($this->session);
echo'</pre>';
```

The following changes on each refresh:

```
[session_id] => 8ebbdc82de64fe302fe7e02347d29ecc
```

I am also now unable to login to the site (developing on localhost).

QUESTION:

1) Why have these changes in config.php now killed the website?

2) How do I fix this problem?

NOTE:
I have added a mysql table called "cisessions" to the db, and followed all instructions at:

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html

in the section titled: What is Session Data?

Any other help/advise appreciated guys...

Comment: What version of CI are you using? I would recommend the sess_match_ip to FALSE. Also session_id is ok to change on update. Can you give some code, on how you check if a user is logged in ? Or the log in process.

Comment: The bad thing is: CodeIgniter couldn't resist rolling their own session implementation, which is likely to be broken. What's wrong with PHP sessions?

Comment: CodeIgniter 213..  Login process: put user data into session via jquery and redirects to my_home.  Login checking: I check session userdata for a logged_in flag and redirect to login page if it is not set.  The login code worked fine before I made those changes to config.php.    @sven were using CI for MVC so it seemed logical to also use CI sessions.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the Encryption class or the Session class you MUST set an encryption key.

```
$config['encryption_key'] = 'your_encryption_key_here';
```

or try to leave blank cookie_domain

```
$config['cookie_prefix'] = "";
$config['cookie_domain'] = "";
```